# How to do client authentication in statsD server?

Tags: graphite, statsd, graphite-carbon

I have installed StatsD on debian using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-statsd-to-collect-arbitrary-stats-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04

Here using `echo "sample.set:50|s" | nc -u -w0 127.0.0.1 8125`   we can send log data to StatsD server. Using this anyone can send the logs to server.

How can I restrict to only predefined client such that those who have already registered can send data to StatsD server?

Answer (score 0):

StatsD can't do such thing since the only thing it should do is metric aggregation.

You can write a customized StatsD proxy, as our team did, to finish things like key-routing, authentication and monitoring.

After that you can use something like iptables to only receive packets from StatsD proxy on your StatsD machine.